# How to send multible g-code comands via pySerial without time-delay

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial, g-code

I have a python script that creates a serial connection to my Arduino-Mega (ramps1. 4). I am using the pyserial library, with which I send G-Code commands via the COM. There "Marlin 2.0x" reads the input and acts on any G-Code.

So far everything works. I can write any G-Code via **serial.write()** and Marlin understands it. But unfortunately I had to add a time delay if I want to act on multiple commands.
Is there a nice way of circumventing that?

Here is an example code of Extruding 1mm of Filament twice.

```
import serial
import time  

ser1 = serial.Serial('COM3', 250000)
time.sleep(1)
ser1.write(('G92 E1\n').encode())
time.sleep(1)
ser1.write(('G92 E1\n').encode())
```

Ideally it'd look like this without the delays:

```
import serial
import time  

ser1 = serial.Serial('COM3', 250000)
ser1.write(('G92 E1\n').encode())
ser1.write(('G92 E1\n').encode())
```

But then commands get skipped.

Comment: *"I send G-Code commands ... I want to act on multiple commands"* -- That's contradictory.  *"Act on"* usually means "receive and/or process"* rather than transmit.  *"I had to add a time delay"* -- Apparently you've written your code to *hose* the device with commands, and not bother to read any responses that would throttle transmission.  RTM! https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/2.0.x/docs/Queue.md#synchronization  ***"Marlin replies "ok" ... well-behaved hosts will wait for this message"***

Comment: *"Is there a nice way of circumventing that?"* -- Can't tell if you're properly leery of using  fixed delays, or simply trying to keep your code short & simple. Perhaps you need to learn how to compose a [procedure](http://www.easypythondocs.com/procedures.html) (e.g. **send_gcode(...)**) that would perform both the write and then read the response for each command.

Comment: hmm. well your example of "hosing the device with commands" is somewhat true.
It seems I have a lot to learn with communication. But your link is a start. Thanks